# Significance of modes in a distribution

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, mixture-distribution, mode, multimodality

I have several datasets with angular measurements, i.e. circular values from 0 to $2\pi$. These datasets tend to have peaks at 0 and/or $\pi$, and I need to tell if the peaks are detected/significant. There are several approaches to related problems I found, but they don't seem to answer the question of individual peak (mode) significance:

- Fitting a mixture model with a uniform component + 2 gaussians at 0 and $\pi$, and getting the posterior for the parameters. The posterior means for weights of each component are basically always distinct from zero , even when fitting to a uniform distribution. So this cannot be used to assess peak significance.
- Different multimodality tests: only test for the number of modes, and don't give their locations.

So I'm looking for help and suggestions - what are better ways to do this?

Comment: Since you want to perform a hypothesis test, can you say more specifically what your null hypothesis is?

Comment: @user20160 there is not a single hypothesis to test here, but a combination of two: "is there a mode at 0" and "is there a mode at pi". Corresponding null hypotheses are that the distribution has no mode at those locations.